# Will yellow undergrowth rhubarb leaves turn green?

Tags: rhubarb

My rhubarb colony has a couple yellow leaves, but everything on the surface prior to picking was green. Will the yellow leaves turn green?

Comment: Old leaves? Young leaves? And as usual: pictures, please!

Comment: transplanted plant, not sure on the age, since we split all of our rhubarb off the ones they had on the farm growing up.